# Is there a way using javascript to collect events from Google Docs,Slides etc?

Tags: javascript, google-workspace, gsuite-addons

Wondering if there's a workaround or method to retrieve the contents in the document itself, just like Microsoft Office using an add-in is able to retrieve and display the contents in the document.

Comment: You can do it using Google script

Comment: @sajalsuraj but google script/js can't run change triggers on google docs. I'm not sure if you know any workaround